# Password protect html page

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, password-protection

I need to tack some simple password protection onto arbitrary html files.  It does need need to be secure, but just keep out the random roff-raff.  I tried using the below JS:

```
var password; 
    var thePassword="secretpassword"; 
    password=prompt('Enter Password',' '); 
    if (password==thePassword) { alert('Correct Password! Click OK to Enter!'); }
    else { window.location="http://www.google.com/"; }
```

This works fine in Firefox, but seems that the prompt function fails in IE and so we always redirect to google...

Any suggestions on how to do a simple password protection using straight HTML pages?

EDIT: to be clear, it works fine in Firefox, and in IE does not even prompt with a popup asking to "Enter Password"

Comment: The code seems to work fine for me on IE9.  I just ran it in this jsfiddle and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/KkMRS/.  What version of IE are you running?  I'd suggest putting an alert on what the actual value is coming back from the prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Works fine for me in IE.  Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/U2n3P/

One possible reason it may not be working is that you're populating the prompt with an empty space, by using `' '`, so when you start typing there may be a space at the end.  Change the prompt to:

```
password=prompt('Enter Password', '');
```

FYI, I know you said you didn't need this to be super secure, but you might as well add ***some*** security.  Get an MD5 library and do, instead:

```
var thePassword = "md5encodedpassword";
password=prompt('Enter Password',' ');
if(md5(password) != thePassword){
```

Comment: the if statement I have is correct.  I told you it works fine in Firefox.  I'll look into the MD5 suggestion though!

Comment: because it ignores the statement that the code posted doesn't work in IE.  IE ignores JS popups.  I can't rightly use a popup like this for a password if IE will just ignore it.

Comment: What do you mean IE ignores JS popups?!?  `prompt` works perfectly well in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Name the secure page or directory the md5 hashed password.

```
function isThere(url) {
    var req= new AJ(); // XMLHttpRequest object
    try {
        req.open("HEAD", url, false);
        req.send(null);     
        return req.status== 200 ? true : false;
    }
    catch (er) {
        return false;
    }
}
password=prompt('Enter Password',' '); 
password=md5(password);
if (isThere(md5 + "/") { window.location = password + "/"; }
else { alert("incorrect"); }
```

Comment: please comment why you vote it down, so far this is the only answer who allow you to protect the page without giving away the protected password or page.